# IOS Operating System - Brightness Increase Past Limit

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, brightness

Thanks in advance,

For those familiar with IOS, I was wondering if it's possible to program it to exceed the brightness limit, and if so is it legal/safe. Thanks again.

Jon

Comment: i doubt this would be possible without hacking the hardware

Answer (score 0):

Without altering hardware or possibly going deeper into the root system it is not going to be possible. The limits are set as they are for safety reasons by Apple themselves or hardware limitations (if they could make it brighter they likely would). However, legally you are free to try and increase the brightness all you want, it will just void your warranty.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thoughtful answer it's greatly appreciated!

Comment: @jonathanmclellan No problem. Sorry it's not an option. Make sure to accept/upvote the answer if you are satisfied with it!